# Column name regex - Pandas

Tags: regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which there are columns with names:

```
DATE
YEARS
DAY
MONTH
YEAR
```

and a host of other columns

I am trying to extract columns from  a dataframe which match this criterion

```
df_date = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains(r'^DATE$|^YEARS$|^DAY$|^MONTH$|^YEAR&')]
```

In this case, column `YEAR` is not filtered.

Comment: Shouldn't there be `$` instead of `&` after `YEAR` in your regex? Also, if these are actual column names, why doesn't `df[['DATE', 'YEARS', 'DAY', 'MONTH', 'YEAR']]` work?

Comment: Yes that worked.